# Calculate Memory Address

Tags: embedded, ram, binary

I know this is a simple arithmetic question for many of you, but I can't figure out how to solve this problem.

In a uController (this is an example, it doesn't matter which one) SRAM1 has SRAM1_BASEADDRESS = 0x20000000. I also know that SRAM2 (connected just after SRAM1) has size 112KB.

1. What is the SRAM2_BASEADDRESS ?
2. Is the number 0x20000000 (which is clearly in hexadecimal) a DWORD? A WORD? If yes, why?

**EDIT:** thanks to some users in the responses received, I realized the typo in the question that makes the question unresolvable. Correction:
SRAM1 and SRAM2 are mapped to address 0x20000000, first there is SRAM1 and then SRAM2.
If SRAM1 has size 112kb, what is the address of SRAM2?
**SOLUTION:**
112kb = 114688 bytes = 0x1C000.
0x20000000 + 0x1C000 = 0x2001C000

Comment: Why wouldn't it be SRAM1_BASEADDRESS + 112KB?

Comment: Exactly, but I don't quite understand how to sum (I'm such a beginner). I should convert 112KB to HEX and add it to SRAM1_BASEADDRESS .. right?

Comment: If you're doing it by hand, yes convert both to the same form. If you're on a computer, most programming languages allow you to write x=0x0001+1 and will handle all conversions automatically to get decimal 2.

Comment: Thanks. Let's assume to doing by hand. I should convert 112 KB (it's dec) to HEX .. so the number 112000 (bytes) to HEX? So 1 B580. I think I am doing something wrong. Or maybe only 12? I don't know how to proceed

Comment: Kilobyte isn't 1000 bytes.

Comment: If you want to know how to do addition on pen and paper, edit your question to ask about it rather than memory addresses.

Comment: Also the correct address must be in MCU datasheet and/or reference guide, where the memory map is depicted. So it can be verified from there if the memory addresses are even contiguous. This sounds like it's about 32-bit ARM Cortex MCU. If you would state which exact MCU it is we can look at the documentation.

Comment: You can’t tell from the info given. It’s like asking “chapter one of a book starts at page 4, chapter two comes after chapter one and is 40 pages long, what page does chapter two start on?” You need to know how long chapter one is.

Comment: I'm assuming there's either a typo in the original question you were given, or you've transcribed it incorrectly. As GodJihyo points out, you need to know the size of SRAM1 to find the start of SRAM2. The size of SRAM2 doesn't help you here.

Comment: @KaleM You seem to have two issues: 1) converting 112 kbyte to hex, and 2) getting the sums straight: you need the size of ram1, not the size of ram2.  If ram1 is also 112 kbyte (which would be an *extremely* strange size for a ram chip), you need 0x20000000 + 0x1c000 = 0x2001c000.  The start address of a block of ram only depends on those below it, not its own size.  The altitude (above sea level, say)  of the second story of a building is the altitude of the first story + height of **first story**.  The base plus the increment.

Answer (score 1):

When doing any form of engineering, the quantity and type of the unit is extremely relevant to know and get right - to the point where this is pretty much the first thing you learn in school. It is certainly prerequisite knowledge before enrolling in any form of computer science or electrical engineering.

There is nothing called "KB" (Kelvin...bar?). In computer science, we do have something which is sloppily called *kb*, where *b* isn't an SI unit for short for *byte*. So *kb* = kilobyte, supposedly.

However, kilobyte is a confusing term in itself. For all SI prefixes *k* = kilo, one thousand. But *kilobyte* often refers to "base 2" memory storage, so a kilobyte often means 1024. Whereas during data communication when we speak of kb/s or kbps, we actually do mean 1000 bits per second.

To make this less ambiguous, IEC invented something called "kibibyte", KiB. This always refers to 1024. Details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte.

Thus you can calculate the next address in your example by 0x20000000 * 0x400, where 0x400 = 1024 = 1 KiB. Please note that memories conventionally comes in even multiples of base 2 forms, so you will most likely have a memory of 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 KiB etc and never 112KiB.